# PLF: [S <: S->S] Subtyping Example Hint

Tags: coq

In Programming Language Foundations, there is an exercise `formal_subtype_instances_tf_2d`, which is asking to prove whether there is a type `S` such that `S <: S->S`. The problem contains a hint that a generalization of the statement should be asserted, and the proof should proceed by induction on a type. The full specifics of the problem and of the simply-typed lambda calculus implementation can be found here: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Sub.html#lab372

I believe there is no such type because I don't believe this implementation of STLC allows recursive types. I have successfully asserted `S <: S->Top`. Proceeding by induction on `S`, I am stuck on the case where `S = S1->S2` and have been struggling to develop a contradiction. Is this the correct approach, or do I need a different assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be to actually make a broader generalization of the entire statement.

`forall S T, S <: <{ T -> S }> -> False` is the generalization I used. It is proved by induction on `S` (with dependent `T`). You can use `sub_inversion_arrow` to find a contradiction in all but one case, when `S = S1->S2`.

The `S = S1->S2` is proved by inversion on the hypothesis. This creates three cases which can be solved by the following:

1. Follows from hypotheses and rewriting.
2. Applying `sub_inversion_arrow` in one of the newly generated hypotheses, and then noticing that `S2 <: S1->S2` (this can be done by developing a lemma about the subtyping relations when `S1->S2 <: T1->T2`, and then by transitivity of subtyping), then the rest follows from hypotheses.
3. Follows from hypotheses.

The proof for the exercise follows by applying this generalization theorem in the hypothesis.

Comment: `I believe there is no such type because I don't believe this implementation of STLC allows recursive types` Was this incorrect then?

Comment: I believe the statement is still correct. In this answer, S <: T->S would be the "recursive" type I was referring to, since S appears on both sides of the subtyping, but it doesn't make sense for the implementation in the book. Otherwise, we could say S <: T->(T->...->(T->S)...) infinitely by function subtyping, and since there aren't recursive types, S cannot be an infinite arrow type. Thus the original proposition is false, and the proof is done by proving a generalization of the original proposition is false.